# Create a HashMap from an Array in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to fill a `HashMap[K,ArrayBuffer[V]]` with elements from an `Array[(K,V)]`.

I've tried to use multimap but it seems it doesn't support `ArrayBuffer` but only `Set`.

I ended up with this code :

```
val hashmap = list.foldLeft(HashMap.empty[K, ArrayBuffer[V]]){ (acc, pair) =>
  acc.getOrElseUpdate(pair._1, ArrayBuffer.empty[V]) += pair._2
  acc
}
```

Is there any more elegant/efficient way to do it ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `Array[k,v]`? I don't really get it.

Comment: @mfirry sorry it's an Array[(k,v)]. I've tried groupBy(_._1) but doesn't give me a proper result.

Answer (score 0):

```
val source = Array(1 -> "one", 1 -> "ein", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three")
val result = source.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
println(result.mapValues(_.toList))
```

- `source` is an example data, which you could have. `1` has 2 values: `one` and `ein`.
- result is built using `groupBy` and `mapValues`
- `println` calls `.toList` in order to call pretty `toString` on List, because `toString` on `Array` does not print elements.

Comment: Be careful with `mapValues`; it doesn't create a new `Map`, it only returns a *view* to a `Map`, meaning that if you access a key more than once, it will do repeat (non-trivial) work.  If you want a new `Map`, just use `.map{case (k,v) => (k, f(v))}`.